# Filter by the nearest date in the month in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
    the_debt_pay_id varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    the_debtor_id varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    the_debt_paid timestamp NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_a 
VALUES ('LMUS0100', '32457601', '2020-03-01 06:59:32'),
       ('LMUS0202', '02377862', '2020-03-02 07:30:59'),
       ('LMUS0301', '40367879', '2020-03-02 09:34:20');

CREATE TABLE table_b
(
    the_debtor_id varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    the_invoice_id varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    the_invoice_created date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_b
VALUES ('02377862', 'BE000017', '2020-02-04'),
       ('32457601', 'BE000018', '2020-03-01'),
       ('02377862', 'BE000019', '2020-03-03'),
       ('40367879', 'BE000020', '2020-03-17'),
       ('40367879', 'BE000021', '2020-03-19'),
       ('32457601', 'BE000022', '2020-04-01');
```

What I want is, given `the_debtor_id`, to obtain `the_debt_pay_id` and `the_invoice_id` based on its nearest date in the month from `the_debtor_paid` and `the_invoice_created`, and finally count one or more occurrences in the month. This should be the expected table:

```
the_debt_pay_id    the_invoice_id    hits
LMUS0100           BE000018          1
LMUS0202           BE000019          1
LMUS0301           BE000020          2
```

I'm kind of stuck because table_b is not indexed by `the_debt_pay_id`. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does that make any sense? Usually, an invoice is sent *before* the payment, and people don't always pay right away.

Comment: Hello @LaurenzAlbe, in fact in some countries people pay and the invoice can be delayed and sent after the payment.

Answer (score 1):

Although typically a good idea to index the join column there is nothing ***requiring*** it. You can join on just about anything provided you can create a valid boolean expression for it. The join for here is simply that the the_debtor_id from each table matches. Ticker is date manipulation for determination of the "nearest date" and the number of invoices (hits) in the month. See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cd8d2a69dd1c9f89788af2e976692468).

```
select distinct on(the_debt_pay_id)
       the_debt_pay_id,the_invoice_id, hits
  from ( 
         select a.the_debt_pay_id
              , b.the_invoice_id
              , count(*) over(partition by a.the_debtor_id, extract('month' from b.the_invoice_created) 
                                  order by a.the_debtor_id ) hits
           from table_a a 
           join table_b b 
             on b.the_debtor_id = a.the_debtor_id
          order by a.the_debt_pay_id 
                 , greatest(a.the_debt_paid,b.the_invoice_created::timestamp)-
                   least(a.the_debt_paid,b.the_invoice_created::timestamp)  
       ) s;
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the part regarding table_b not being indexed by the_debt_pay_id

The constant here appears to be `the_debtor_id` You can pull the tables together in a select statement and assign an alias to each table (in this case f + g)

You can then join them this way

```
SELECT 

f.the_debtor_id,
f.the_debt_pay_id,
g.the_invoice_id


FROM table_a f
JOIN table_b g

ON g.the_debtor_id = f.the_debtor_id
```

Comment: Hello Dallas, you're missing the point that the month is what makes the selection. Anyway thanks for your time.